# Where is the checkout validation in Opencart

Tags: php, jquery, opencart

The problem I'm having is that the in the "Delivery Method" section, the Ajax is failing to validate for some reason.

In the code below (from checkout/checkout.tpl), the BeforeSend and complete functions are firing off, but the function in the success is not firing off.

Can anyone tell me where 'index.php?route=checkout/shipping_method/validate' is set?

Thank you

```
$('#button-shipping-method').live('click', function() {
   $.ajax({
      url: 'index.php?route=checkout/shipping_method/validate',
      type: 'post',
      data: $('#shipping-method input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #shipping-method textarea'),
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function() {
         $('#button-shipping-method').attr('disabled', true);
         $('#button-shipping-method').after('<span class="wait">&nbsp;<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/loading.gif" alt="" /></span>');
      },   
      complete: function() {
         $('#button-shipping-method').attr('disabled', false);
         $('.wait').remove();
      },         
      success: function(json) {
         $('.warning, .error').remove();

         if (json['redirect']) {
            location = json['redirect'];
         } else if (json['error']) {
            if (json['error']['warning']) {
               $('#shipping-method .checkout-content').prepend('<div class="warning" style="display: none;">' + json['error']['warning'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

               $('.warning').fadeIn('slow');
            }         
         } else {
            $.ajax({
               url: 'index.php?route=checkout/payment_method',
               dataType: 'html',
               success: function(html) {
                  $('#payment-method .checkout-content').html(html);

                  $('#shipping-method .checkout-content').slideUp('slow');

                  $('#payment-method .checkout-content').slideDown('slow');

                  $('#shipping-method .checkout-heading a').remove();
                  $('#payment-method .checkout-heading a').remove();

                  $('#shipping-method .checkout-heading').append('<a>Modify &raquo;</a>');   

               },
               error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                  alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
               }
            });               
         }
      },
      error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
         alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
      }
   });   
});
```

Comment: No error. Just doesn't go on to the next stage in the checkout

Answer (score 4):

As url shows the controller structure the `validate` function you can find in the class having name `ControllerCheckoutShippingMethod` which is located in

> catalog\controller\checkout\shipping_method.php

Answer (score 0):

> checkout use many page  for 
>   as your Ajax URL is

```
url: 'index.php?route=checkout/shipping_method/validate',
```

> it  retrieve data from page checkout/shipping_method.php with function
>   validate.
>
> and 
>   guest checkout

```
checkout/guest.php    


public function save() {//this function consist validation

checkout/shipping_method.php
checkout/payment_method.php
```

> you can check by using console in firebug which will make you clear
>   about which section or page is calling through ajax is current running.